# Android Studio will not open in Windows 10

Tags: android, android-studio

I've just downloaded and installed Android Studio on a Windows 7 PC without issue.

For a Windows 10 (x64), it's a totally different matter - whatever I do Studio refuses to even open - no splash screen nothing. I know there are many posts/Youtube videos saying "all" you have to do is ensure the environment variables are correct - which they absolutely are!

I've setup all the required environment variables, path is correct and points to Gradle 3-4, have even installed Java to off the root of C: in a folder without any spaces (as advised by an obscure post I read somewhere) and Studio is configured as Administrator. If I even delete the environment variables, point them to invalid locations, nothing.

If I run the EXE (Studio64.exe) from a command prompt- nothing. I have no Studio.bat btw.

Java is installed correctly (java -version is ok : 1.8.0.144). I have even made the local user owner (with full control) of all Android, Java folders.

I seriously do not know what else to try.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

On a side note, I've installed Studio on my work PC (also windows 10) and this works like a charm. Also, on the Win7 install I've even removed ALL environment variables and Studio still works running Studio64.exe(!!???)

I've attached screenshots of my environment variables:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Weired, no need to pre setup any env variablr to make Android Studio come up, Please try this:
1. Restart computer, make sure you have enough availble RAM to run it. 
2. Make sure you are Admin.
3. Make sure you've downloaded the right Android Studio x86/x64.
4. Maybe uninstall and reinstall using this Official android guide: https://developer.android.com/studio/install.html.
please post your system details, don't foget to answer this question and mark it as solved if you find a solution.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. The PC has been restarted many, times times, the correct  version of Android Studio has been installed (uninstalled and installed an annoying amount of times), admin user - I'm freelance mobile app developer so have done this quite often and have never come across anything like this.
I've created a dual boot on the PC for Windows 7, installed AS on this and it works fine, so the PC is perfectly capable of running it (16gb RAM, i5-3570 (4.2ghx), Windows 10 home (x64). It works on the Windows 7 partition, but I really, really want it to run on the main win10.